# Oracle SQL: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My oracl sql command will try to find the network package fees which the total fees will be higher than the average fees. But it comes out the error saying: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

'cost_per_hour' will be in the entity named 'menu' while 'start_hours' and 'end_hours' will be in the entity named 'user_log'

Here are my codes:

```
SELECT
    network_pacakage
    to_char(cost_per_hours *(start_hours - end_hours)), '$999.99') AS total_costs
FROM
     menu m
    JOIN user_log ul ON m.package_id = ul.package_id
WHERE
    (
        SELECT
            cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours)) AS total_charter_cost
        FROM
              menu m
            JOIN user_log ul ON m.package_id = ul.package_id
    ) > (
        SELECT
            AVG(cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours)) AS ave_total_charter_cost
        FROM
                 menu m
            JOIN user_log ul ON m.package_id = ul.package_id
    )
ORDER BY
    total_costs DESC;
```

Can you suggest a solution? THANKS!

Comment: you really ought to get in the habit of "upvoting" any reply you find helpful, and "accepting" one of them whenever possible!

Answer (score 0):

The error caused by this query return more than 1 row as result:

```
SELECT cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours)) AS total_charter_cost
FROM menu m
JOIN user_log ul ON m.package_id = ul.package_id
```

you might need `sum` to make this subquery return a specific value

Comment: can you be more specific? so it should be like SELECT SUM(cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours))) AS total_charter_cost ?

Comment: your join tables might have more than 1 row then the select from (table with more than 1 row) return more than 1 row. 
More than 1 row > 1 row is uncomparable

Comment: but i think in this select statement, i calculate the costs of each pacakage. So i don't know how i can fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
WITH average AS (
 SELECT AVG(cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours)) AS ave_total_charter_cost
 FROM menu m -- likely you dont need this table for this query...
   JOIN user_log ul 
     ON m.package_id = ul.package_id
)
SELECT
  network_pacakage,
  to_char(cost_per_hours *(start_hours - end_hours)), '$999.99') AS total_costs
FROM menu m
  JOIN user_log ul 
      ON m.package_id = ul.package_id
  JOIN average a
      ON 1=1
WHERE cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours) > a.ave_total_charter_cost
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

I calculate the average in the cte (`WITH`) to avoid calculate this value many times. Maybe the execution plan do it in the query, but just in case...

Comment: can cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours) exist in where clause?

Comment: Yes, it acts as a calculated field to do the comparison. I have changed the `ORDER BY`, not sure you can order by an alias.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare each row with the average, you don't need to select it again, just use the selected columns:

```
WHERE
    cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours) > 
    (SELECT AVG(cost_per_hours * (start_hours - end_hours))
     FROM menu m
     JOIN user_log ul ON m.package_id = ul.package_id
    )
```